# Firestore rules on subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a "game" collection on firestore with a "levels" sub-collection. I'm trying to set-up the security rules so that you can only access game or level you created.

All documents (games or levels) have an `authorId` field with the uid of the user that created them. I have try this rule but still got an `Missing or insufficient permissions` error:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /games/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if document.data.authorId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

I have tried the following rules too with no success:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /games/{game}/levels/{level} {
        allow read, write: if level.data.authorId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /games/{game} {
     allow read, write: if game.data.authorId == request.auth.uid;     

       match /levels/{level} {
          allow read, write: if level.data.authorId == request.auth.uid;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the reference documentation, [resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.resource) is the object that contains the document data that the user is trying to write.  You use its [data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data) property to get a hold of its field values.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /games/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if resource.data.authorId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes it works. `document` is only the document name, not the full object.

Answer (score 2):

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /data/{uid}/temperature
    /{document=**}{
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /data/{uid}/blood_pressure
    /{document=**}{
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
   
  }
}
```

I did this to access subcollections "**blood_pressure**" and "**temperature**" for only authenticated users. It works fine for me.